# How can I wait for a string from a server with IdTCPClient?

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcpclient, indy

I have a problem with IdTelnet (indy 10.1). I can't read the data from a server in Unicode mode. and now I want to write the telnet terminal with IdTCPClient.

The server sometimes send one line and sometimes more and more lines. But there is not a fixed time between sending.

Now my problem is that when I must read data from InBuffer.

Or when I must use the ReadLn function to read the data from the server, how many times must I run the ReadLn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TIdTelnet` is a multithreaded component. It has an internal thread that continuously reads from the socket, firing the `TIdTelnet.OnDataAvailable` event whenever a buffer of data is available.

`TIdTelnet` is a `TIdTCPClient` descendant. Look in the IdTelnet.pas source file to see how it is implemented. You can do something similar in your own code, calling `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` in your own thread, eg:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FConn: TIdTCPConnection;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AConn: TIdTCPConnection); reintroduce;
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(AConn: TIdTCPConnection);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FConn := AConn;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  S: String;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    S := FConn.IOHandler.ReadLn(...);
    ...
  end;
end;

var
  Thread: TMyThread = nil;

procedure TForm1.ConnectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  try
    Thread := TMyThread.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  except
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DisconnectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Thread) then Thread.Terminate;
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
  finally
    if Assigned(Thread) then
    begin
      Thread.WaitFor;
      FreeAndNil(Thread);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you don't want to use a thread, then you can use a timer instead. To make sure your timer thread (such as the main thread) is not blocked unnecessarily, use the `TIdIOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource()` method with a small timeout whenever the `TIdIOHandler.InputBuffer` is empty, before then calling `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` only when data is available, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.ConnectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  ReadTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.DisconnectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReadTimer.Enabled := False;
  IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm1.ReadTimerElapsed(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
begin
  if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
    if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;
  S := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn(...);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if I want use idTelnet, how i can change the encoding of the buffer? in icTCPClienet I use ReadLn with TEncoding.UTF8 as argument and it works well.

Comment: TIdTelnet gives you raw buffers (after decoding Telnet sequences) as they arrive. Buffers do not have encodings, strings do. You have to copy the raw data into your own buffer and then read completed strings/lines from that as needed after determining when complete strings/lines have finished being buffered. Indy has several functions for extracting strings/lines from TIdBuffer, TStream, and TIdBytes buffers. Otherwise, don't use TIdTelnet, use TIdTCPClient with your own ReaLn() thread/timer, like I showed you.

Answer (score 1):

**A syncronous solution for IdTCPClient**

I was looking for a solution which would "wait" for the response, this seems to work quite well for what I'm doing if I play with the readTimeOut setting and disconnect the client from the Server side after a WriteLn from the server.  Based on the readTimeOut this will disconnect after that is reached with the IoHandler.ReadLn();

```
function sendTCPCommand(command: string): string;
var
 lines, lineInput: String;
 tcpClient : TIdTcpClient;

begin
  tcpClient := TidTcpClient.Create(nil);
  try
    with tcpClient do
    begin
      Port := 80;
      Host := 127.0.0.1;

      try
        ReadTimeOut := 5000; //Adjust according to demands, each readln event uses it
        lines := '';
        connect;
        IoHandler.WriteLn(command);
        lineInput := IoHandler.ReadLn();
        while (lineInput <> '') do
        begin
          lines := lines + lineInput;
          lineInput := IoHandler.ReadLn();
          if (lineInput = '') then
          begin
            Disconnect; //ignores timeout when finished reading or getting nothing
          end;
        end;
        Result := lines;
      except
        On E:Exception do
        begin
          Result := E.Message;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    tcpClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```