# Delphi (Indy) Clients sends server request, how to wait for response?

Tags: delphi, client, wait, indy

I have just managed to get the client (IdTCPClient) to send a message to the server (IdTCPServer) as required. But how do I get the client to wait for a response, or time out appropriately?

Cheers,
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client can read the response with the IOHandler.Readxxx methods, most of them allow to set a timeout. The read timeout can also be specified on the IdTCPClient.IOHandler  directly.

```
procedure TForm1.ReadTimerElapsed(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
begin
  ... 
  // connect
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;

  // send data
  ...

  // use one of the Read methods to read the response.
  // some methods have a timeout parameter, 
  // and others set a timeout flag 

  S := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn(...);

  if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedOut then
    ...
  else
    ...


end;
```

See also: [How can I wait for a string from a server with IdTCPClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989133/how-can-i-wait-for-a-string-from-a-server-with-idtcpclient)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

Client:

```
procedure TForm1.SendCmdButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Resp: String;
begin
  Client.IOHandler.WriteLn('CMD');
  Resp := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
end;
```

Server:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Cmd: String;
begin
  Cmd := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  ...
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(...);
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `TIdTCPConnection.SendCmd()` method instead:

Client:

```
procedure TForm1.SendCmdButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // any non-200 reply will raise an EIdReplyRFCError exception
  Client.SendCmd('CMD', 200);
  // Client.LastCmdResult.Text will contain the response text
end;
```

Server:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Cmd: String;
begin
  Cmd := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  ...
  if (Command is Successful) then
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('200 ' + ...);
  else
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('500 Some Error Text here');
end;
```

In this latter scenario, if you switch to `TIdCmdTCPServer`, you can use the `TIdCmdTCPServer.CommandHandlers` collection to define your commands at design-time and assign per-command `OnCommand` event handlers to them, instead of using the `OnExecute` event to read and parse the commands manually, eg:

```
// OnCommand event handler for 'CMD' TIdCommandHandler object...
procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1CMDCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
  ...
  if (Command is Successful) then
    ASender.Reply.SetReply(200, ...);
  else
    ASender.Reply.SetReply(500, 'Some Error Text here');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used the Indy components (or Delphi for that matter) but I believe that the TIdTCPClient doesn't behave asynchronously so there's no OnData or similar event that you can set.

You will need to call one of the read methods from the parent class (TIdTCPConnection) such as ReadLn(...).  Alternatively you could look at using one of the many Indy components that are TIdTCPClient descendants.

Documentation for the class can be found [here](http://www.iternet.biz/Knowledge/Indy9/007827.html).

Comment: Right; so let's say the server just wrote some value out:

AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(EntryRecord.Text);

What should the client do to recieve this? I am a little confused about this step.

Thanks for the fast reply, Dylan!

Comment: `WriteLn()` sends a CRLF-delimited string.  The `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` method reads a delimited string, where `LF` is the default delimiter (ReaDLn() accounts for `CRLF` internally when `LF` is the delimiter).